# Form not being populated with properties from component in unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-material, karma-jasmine

I have a component with an `office` object that is passed in from a container. The properties in this object populate a form, which works as expected in the browser, however if I assign mock data to this object in my unit test and check the value of one of the inputs, it is apparently empty. In my test below, the first two assertions pass, but I get the following error message with the 3rd:

> Expected '' to be 'Test Name'.

I tried adding a `fakeAsync` wrapper and then used the `tick()` right before I did `fixture.detectChanges()`, but that didn't work either. Why isn't the input being populated with the data from `office` like it does in the browser?

Here are the versions of some of my node modules:

- angular 7.2.8
- material 7.3.3
- karma 4.0.1
- jasmine-core 3.3.0
- karma-jasmine 2.0.1

**component.ts:**

```
export class FormComponent {
  @Input() office: Office;
  @Input() officeLoading: boolean;

  ...
}
```

**component.html:**

```
<form *ngIf="!officeLoading" (ngSubmit)="saveForm(form)" #form="ngForm" novalidate>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      class="company-name"
      matInput 
      placeholder="Company Name" 
      type="text"
      name="companyName"
      required
      #companyName="ngModel"
      [ngModel]="office?.companyName">
    <mat-error *ngIf="companyName.errors?.required && companyName.dirty">
      Company name is required
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
 ...
</form>
```

**component.spec.ts**

```
describe('FormComponent', () => {
  let component: FormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormComponent>;
  let el: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        MatInputModule,
        OverlayModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({}),
      ],
      declarations: [FormComponent],
      providers: [Actions, MatSnackBar, Store],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    el = fixture.debugElement;
    component.office = null;
    component.officeLoading = false;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should fill out form based on what comes back from API', () => {
    expect(component.office).toBe(null);
    expect(el.query(By.css('input.company-name')).nativeElement.value).toBe('');
    component.office = {
      companyName: 'Test Name',
    };
    component.officeLoading = false;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(el.query(By.css('input.company-name')).nativeElement.value).toBe(
      'Test Name',
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Please see revised answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the fixture to become stable after calling `fixture.detectChanges()`.

```
 fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(el.query(By.css('input.company-name')).nativeElement.value).toBe(
        "Test Name",
      );
    });
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/directive-testing-yxuyuk?embed=1&file=app/app.component.spec.ts